# PayPal Sandbox error 10501

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have Sandbox Business-Pro Account.
I many times check my settings in code, but every time i got a message:

> {"error":[{"L_ERRORCODE":"10501","L_SHORTMESSAGE":"Invalid Configuration","L_LONGMESSAGE":"This transaction
>    cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.","L_SEVERITYCODE":"Error"}]}

I create a new Business-Pro Account, but got the same message.
Someone know how i can fix this problem?

All solution what i found in web not working for me.

Thank!!

Comment: I create more accounts and can make two times payment per account. But, after i got this message again.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an account configuration question, you should contact [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal.com/mts). They have the access and knowledge to help ensure your account is set up properly.